# scene2d button scaling with libgdx

Tags: android, button, libgdx, scaling, scene2d

I don't know if it is just me, but [drawables](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/Drawable.html) confuse me. Are they intended to keep the size they are given, or is there a way to scale the image within them? I understand they can use ninepatch to fill certain areas by stretching an image, but I want to scale the image that it stretches. I am using a [TextButton](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/TextButton.html)
for my menu buttons, but they are way too big, and I would love to know how to scale them. I am retrieving the skin from an atlas, which has ninepatch images in it.
Here is the settings screen:
[image: The settings screen]
Here are the images in the pack I am using:
[image: ninepatch images packed]
Here is the initialization of the TextureAtlas, and Skin:

```
buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("buttons/buttons.pack"));
buttonSkin = new Skin(buttonAtlas);
```

Here is the initialization of that menu button.

```
TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
textButtonStyle.up = Assets.buttonSkin.getDrawable("bluebutton");
textButtonStyle.down = Assets.buttonSkin.getDrawable("redbutton");
textButtonStyle.font = font;

buttonMenu = new TextButton("Menu", textButtonStyle);
buttonMenu.pad(20.0f);
buttonMenu.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        game.fade.startFadeOut();
        super.clicked(event, x, y);
    }
});
```

And perhaps I could change how I put it in the table, or how I put the table in the stage?

```
table.add(buttonMenu).width(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/4);
stage.addActor(table);
```

As a last resort I suppose I could attempt creating my own text button actor that I could scale, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you know that your images are too big: The best would be to scale the images themselves to a smaller size and then use the TexturePacker too generate a new TextureAtlas that contain the smaller images.

Anyhow you can scale the image button with the TableLayout if you really want to, see example:

```
table.add(buttonMenu).width(100).height(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer didnt work for me, but i have a solution.

You can make a secondary camera and attach it to your stage.
To scale the table just scale the viewport size of the secondary camera

An example would be:

```
//Heres where you set the scale of your buttons and your table
Camera secondaryCamera = new Camera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * scale, 
                                    Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * scale); 


Stage stage = new Stage();
Table table = new Table();
ImageButton button = new ImageButton(drawableUp, drawableDown, drawableChecked);
table.setFillParent(true);

stage.getViewport().setCamera(secondaryCamera);

table.add(ImageButton);
stage.addActor(table);
```

This works great when your using it for touch controls. You can use a table for the entire UI and scale it to your liking independent of your other game items;

Answer (score 0):

`table.add(buttonMenu).width(100).height(100);` should work, and you just need to adjust the `width` and `height` parameters to your liking, or you can use the `setBounds` method. Here is an example:

```
    TextButton myButton = new TextButton("Press Me", style);
    myButton.setBounds(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, width, height);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set size of `Drawable` in `ButtonStyle` to resize your `Button`:

```
float scale = 0.5f;
float currentHeight = textButtonStyle.up.getMinHeight();
textButtonStyle.up.setMinHeight(currentHeight * scale);
```

For more information, see [official document for layout](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#layout):

> UI widgets do not set their own size and position. Instead, the parent widget sets the size and position of each child. **Widgets provide a minimum, preferred, and maximum size that the parent can use as hints.** Some parent widgets, such as Table and Container, can be given constraints on how to size and position the children. To give a widget a specific size in a layout, the widget's minimum, preferred, and maximum size are left alone and size constraints are set in the parent.

And you can find the implementation of `Button.getPrefHeight()` in the [source code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.java#L250-L256):

```
public float getPrefHeight () {
    float height = super.getPrefHeight();
    if (style.up != null) height = Math.max(height, style.up.getMinHeight());
    if (style.down != null) height = Math.max(height, style.down.getMinHeight());
    if (style.checked != null) height = Math.max(height, style.checked.getMinHeight());
    return height;
}
```