# Re-sizing ImageButton - Scene2d

Tags: libgdx

I am using libgdx + scene2d + box2d. Everything looked ok until I decided to replaced my TextButtons to ImageButton.

I can't get my ImageButton rezided, it always follows the image dimensions. 


Here is my Stage:

```
        stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(camera.viewportWidth,camera.viewportHeight));
```

This how a create my Button:

```
    ImageButtonStyle style = new ImageButtonStyle();
    style.imageUp =  new TextureRegionDrawable(textureButtonPlay);
    ImageButton buttonPlay = new ImageButton(style);
    buttonPlay.setSize(50, 20); //this does not work
```

This how a create my Window and add my Button to it:

```
    WindowStyle windowStyle = new WindowStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE, null);

    windowTryAgain = new Window("", windowStyle);
    windowTryAgain.setMovable(false);
    //windowTryAgain.padTop(20);


    windowTryAgain.setSize(150,150);
    windowTryAgain.setPosition(camera.viewportWidth/2 - windowTryAgain.getWidth()/2,
            camera.viewportHeight/2 - windowTryAgain.getHeight()/2);

    windowTryAgain.row().fill().expandX();
    windowTryAgain.add(buttonPlay).padTop(25).expandX().fillX();
    windowTryAgain.center();
```

Is it possible to resize the Texture or TextureRegion? What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My has issue has been resolved with following piece of code:

windowTryAgain.add(buttonMenu).width(100).height(100);

Then the image will resized accordiantly to the cell width and height.

Credits:

[scene2d button scaling with libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594611/scene2d-button-scaling-with-libgdx)